# Permitir apenas uma instância

Tags: c#, thread, instanciar-objeto

Como fazer com que o meu aplicativo execute apenas 1 instância de uma vez?

```
void Main(string[] s){
//faz algo
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei mais a fundo nas bibliotecas da microsoft e encontei algo parecido com `Mutex`, e interpretei esse código para manter apenas uma instancia.

```
using System.Threading;
namespace MeuNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MeuAplicativo");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
            {
                // faz algo
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Já tens uma instancia em execução!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OBS! Não esqueça de que não pode aplicar `Mutex.ReleaseMutex` diretamente. Ele deve pelo menos fazer algo antes de ser lançado, se não acaba que o Mutex é lançado antes e gerando uma exception.

Fontes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx

Referência:

`Mutex.WaitOne`:
Bloqueia o thread atual até que a instância atual recebe um sinal, usando um TimeSpan para especificar o intervalo de tempo e especificar se deseja sair do domínio de sincronização antes do tempo de espera.(herdado de WaitHandle.)